# K8 jobs run in parallel with hooks

Tags: kubernetes

I have two YAML files containing Kubernetes jobs. Let's call them yaml1 and yaml2. yaml1 contains jobA, while yaml2 contains jobB, jobC, and jobD.

In yaml1, jobA has the annotation helm.sh/hook-weight: -1. This means that jobA will be executed first, followed by jobB, jobC, and jobD [Currently execute in sequential order but the expectation is it should execute in parallel].

I have also added the annotation helm.sh/hook-weight: 1 to jobB, jobC, and jobD. However, they still execute sequentially, even though they have different weights.

My objective is when i install my helm chart i need to have jobB, jobC, and jobD executed in parallel, once jobA has been successfully completed.

Sharing the sample yaml1[containing jobA] and yaml2[containing jobB,jobC]

**yaml1 file sample**

```
{{- if eq .Values.myFlag.restore.enabled true }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: jobA
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: post-install-5
         image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo post-install-job-hook-5 running, weight 5 ; sleep 5']
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  backoffLimit: 3
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 3
  {{- end }}
enter code here
```

**yaml 2 file sample**

```
{{- if eq .Values.myFlag.restore.enabled true }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: jobB
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "3"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: post-install-5
         image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo post-install-job-hook-5 running, weight 5 ; sleep 5']
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  backoffLimit: 3
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 3
  {{- end }}
---
  {{- if eq .Values.myFlag.enabled true}}  
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: jobC
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "3"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: post-install-5
         image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo post-install-job-hook-5 running, weight 5 ; sleep 5']
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
  backoffLimit: 3
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 3
  {{- end }
```